# Prevent user input from doing selection in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, input, user-input, cin

I have a small program that i made to ask the user for the input and stores them into an array.

My question is  if the user enters more then 3 numbers lets say ex: -3 7 2 1 then hits enter

the first 3 will be stored in the array but the last number will be taken as the select input so then it will select option 1.

How would I prevent this in the case that the user does enter more than 3 numbers?

code here

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main() {

    int select;
    int array[3]; 

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cin >> array[i];
    }

    cout<<"select from the following options \n";
    cout<<"enter option 1 to print index 0\n"; 
    cout<<"enter option 2 to print index 1\n"; 
    cout<<"enter option 3 to print index 2\n";
    cin >> select;
    if (select == 1)
    {
        cout <<"\nprinting index 0 with a value of: "<<array[0];
    }
    else if (select == 2)
    {
        cout <<"\nprinting index 1 with a value of: "<<array[1];    
    } 
    else if(select == 3)
    {
        cout <<"\nprinting index 2 with a value of: "<<array[2];
    }
    else 
    {
        cout<<"invalid selection";
        exit(1);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Pic when the user enters more then 3 numbers and hits enter

http://i1154.photobucket.com/albums/p529/strk44/code/picEX.png

Comment: Just take 3 inputs and skip to the end of the line - `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`

Comment: I really wish I can make yours the best answer. Yours worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::getline()` to read the entire line of input, at once, into a `std::string`, then parse out the whitespace-delimited numbers into the individual variables.

Answer (score 0):

Just flush the cin buffer like this:

> fflush(stdin);

before the `cin >> select;`

> cout<<"enter option 3 to print index 2\n";
>
> **fflush(stdin);**
>
> cin >> select;

Answer (score 0):

After reading the first three inputs you use [`std::ifstream::ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) to skip all remaining data up to the next new line character.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    std::cin >> array[i];
}

std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```